# saving output from an while loop in an dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, while-loop, saving-data

I have this `while` loop that shows the days of the year with an interval of 7 but when I try saving it in a dataframe it gives me the total amount of values but I need the values separate.

```
i <- 1
while (i < 365) {
  Date <- print(i)
  i <- i + 7
}
```

Comment: Assigning the output from `print` to a variable is not correct. The better way to do this in R would be something like `mydata <- data.frame(Date = seq(1, 364, 7))`.

Comment: Because R is vectorized, `for` and `while` loops can usually be avoided and replaced with a single line of code as neilfws demonstrates.  R vectorization means that many functions and operations operate with implicit loops.  For example, if you have a vector v1 <- c(1, 2, 3), to multiply each element by 5 in R only requires setting v2 <- 5 * v1  No looping through v1 to multiply each element by 5 is required.  It is a best practice to utilize vectorization as much as possible and use explicit loops as little as possible.